# Prisma Typescript typing when using select to not return the entire object

Tags: typescript, prisma, typing

The good thing about using Prisma is that typesafety is super siple to apply.

Let's go with an example, that I have a user model like the following:

```
model User {
    id                String      @id @default(cuid())
    name              String
    email             String?     @unique
    emailVerified     DateTime?
    image             String?
}
```

When I now query it and put it for example into a state like:

```
import { type User } from "@prisma/client";
const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
```

```
return await prisma.user.findUnique({
   where: {
      id: userId,
   }
});
```

Then the typing would be perfectly fine. Now the problem:

In case I do not want people to be able to query all the information given on a user, I would limit the return by setting a select like this:

```
return await prisma.user.findUnique({
   where: {
      id: userId,
   },
   select: {
      id: true,
      name: true,
   }
});
```

The problem now. Typescript now changes the return object to something super boring like

```
{
   id: string,
   name: string,
}
```

So then I's need to change the state for example to this:

```
import { type User } from "@prisma/client";
const [user, setUser] = useState<{
   id: string,
   name: string,
}| null>(null);
```

And when you add multiple complex includes it just get super messy. Am I missing something obvious on how to limit those types on the frontend?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning a user. You're returning a subset of a user.

So you can make a type that matches yourself with:

```
Pick<User, 'name' | 'id'>
```

Or:

```
Omit<User, 'emailVerfied' | 'image' | 'passwordHash'>
```

And if you use that a lot you can just make your own type to import wherever you want:

```
// somefile.ts
import { type User } from "@prisma/client";
export type PublicUser = Pick<User, 'name' | 'id'>


// my-component.tsx
import { type PublicUser } from './somefile'

const [user, setUser] = useState<PublicUser | null>(null);
```